# How to search posts with two or more certain tags via PostSearchModel?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

Please help me to understand, how to do it.

For example I have 3 tags:

- A;
- B;
- C.

And 3 posts

- Post 1 with tags: A B;
- Post 2 with tags: B C;
- Post 3 with tags: A B C.

I need to search only posts with tags A,B,C. In this example only Post 3 contains these tags.

Comment: are you using `gridview` for search or a normal form? how are you submitting the fields to the searchModel,  add your `post` `postsearch` and `tags` model

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find posts with all three tags, you need to build query with triple join - one join for each tag. Assuming that you have your tags relation defined as:

```
public function getTags() {
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::class, ['id' => 'tag_id'])
        ->viaTable('{{%posts_tags}}', ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

You should be able to get what you want by:

```
$posts = Post::find()
    ->innerJoinWith('tags as tags1', false)
    ->andWhere(['tags1.name' => 'A'])
    ->innerJoinWith('tags as tags2', false)
    ->andWhere(['tags2.name' => 'B'])
    ->innerJoinWith('tags as tags3', false)
    ->andWhere(['tags3.name' => 'C'])
    ->all();
```

Alternatively you may use `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` and count number of matching tags, but this will be unreliable if you allow to assign one tag multiple times to one post.

```
$posts = Post::find()
    ->innerJoinWith('tags', false)
    ->andWhere(['tags.name' => ['A', 'B', 'C']])
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->having('COUNT(*) >= 3')
    ->all();
```